# Index text with translations in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, translation, lemmatization

I'm indexing some articles in Solr with two languages (spanish and basque).
I'm using two lemmatizers, one for each language (Spanish Lemmatizer SL, and Basque lemmatizer BL) and using synonim.

I have four fields for eacyh text field. For example, for the article_body I have:

**body_S** (index and seach with SL)

**body_S2B** (index with SL, translate to Basque and search with BL)

**body_B** (index and search with BL)

**body_B2S** (index with BL, translate to Spanish and search with SL)

I use copyfield from body_S to body_S2B, and body_B to body_B2S.
On search time, if I search in basque I look in body_B and body_S2B, and If i search in spanish I look in body_S and body_B2S.

My question is... Am I doing it right or is there a simpler way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: actually the question is off topic. cause there is no right way in this situation. to me it looks like you doing fine with it. Do you need to have translated fields? will it help to search results?

Comment: Hi @Mysterion,
In Basque country all the people speaks Basque and Spanish. We have news articles on both languages, so would be interesting to search in one language and return both languages articles.

I made those four fields because (as you can see) the index and search methods are different (as we use different lemmatizers in those cases).

I was asking this because it could be any simplear way or somebody had a similar case before.

If it looks like I'm doing fine, that's ok. Thank you.